# Can workers be expected to share fleece jackets without laundering between users?

Tags: health

My workplace has over 15 people doing the same job. It can be a very cold environment. The management has provided 3 fleece jackets and expects the staff to use these when on duty, without laundering between users. Just take the jacket, wear it and put it back.
Is this acceptable practice?

Comment: It's pretty cheap of them, but I think you'll struggle to convince anyone it's some kind of health risk.

Comment: Probably heavily depends on the jurisdiction in which you are working.

Comment: What about simple transmissable bacteria like MRSA? Carriers can be asymptomatic.

Comment: Why are there so few jackets to go around? Unless you're working shifts with only 3 people on duty at a time, isn't there a good chance that you'll have periods where you have far fewer jackets than workers? Do those people just huddle in the corner and shiver?

Comment: Are you wearing these the whole shift, or just sporadically? For example, do you just grab the jacket when you need to go stock the walk-in freezer?

Comment: The question as asked is not the sort of question that works well here at The Workplace.  Instead perhaps ask how you can propose a policy or change to the policy that would provide more sanitary options.  Or if you are unsure if this is safe you could ask about how you can evaluate if the process should be changed.  Either of those questions would be good on topic options

Answer (score 2):

> Is this acceptable practice?

It's rather cheesy, but I've seen it and similar situations before. I've worked for one. At least in my part of the world, it's considered an acceptable practice.

Have you approached management and asked if you could bring your own home-laundered fleece?

Have you asked management if they would purchase a fleece for you and you would launder it yourself?

Comment: I am in the UK. The jackets have the logo, so not acceptable to bring in my own.

Comment: MM id be calling the union/ HSE or anonymously tipping of the local press.

As its the uk protective clothing has to be fit for purpose and for 15 people 3 fleeces doesn't sound good they provide gloves and other gear needed for working in cold environments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in the UK, not familiar with your rules for employment. In the US, if an employee needs protective equipment, the employer is expected to provide it or make the employee aware they are required to purchase as a part of employment. For example, manufacturing may require steel toe boots, these would be listed as an item the employee must have and wear for work. In healthcare, scrubs are required for many areas; however, in the OR they must be sterile, so hospitals provide these to the employees. If you are working in the Family Practice clinic, you are expected to purchase your own.

Suggest doing some research on employment requirements and see if you can find something to support either the purchase for each employee (or daily laundering). Agree with previous commenter, there are many communicable diseases which do not need body fluid or blood and well, just ewwww.

Comment: PHB: "Hey, that sweater you're wearing isn't authorized, you must don the communal fleece and become one with the odors of your fellow workers for the next 8 hours.  Every.  Day." Me: "Nope.  I quit."

Answer (score 1):

It probably *is* acceptable.  But that doesn't mean you shouldn't challenge it.

In your position, I think a sensible approach would be...

1. Chat to your manager about it.  Raise the fact that you feel uncomfortable wearing an unwashed fleece.  Be aware that she may not have the power / budget to change it.
2. Talk to your local union rep.  If you're not part of a union yet, take a look at one which is relevant to your place of work - http://www.worksmart.org.uk/unionfinder/type.php - the rep should be able to tell you what your options are.
3. Finally, ask your other co-workers if they feel the same.  Having several team members push back is likely to be a lot more effective than just having you complain.

Good luck!

Comment: It might be legal but behaviour like this is not acceptable!

Comment: I'd suggest doing #3 before #1.